# DB sort and groupby in php

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there is some framework oder library which allows me to do sort and group by, which would be done in mysql, in PHP on an application level?

A google search didn't help me, yet.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use `SORT` and `GROUP BY` statements in your query?

Comment: Pretty much all the major PHP frameworks out there allow you to define a `SORT` or `ORDER BY` for your query operations. Can you be more specific what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you using mysql/mysqli calls directly, or PDO? If we can see your code as it stands, that would be helpful (edit your answer if you have some).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to do that.

If you want something more advanced, you should have a look into Microsoft's LINQ. There are many variants of LINQ ported to PHP. You can find one [here](http://code.google.com/p/phinq/).

Answer (score 1):

Like the folks who commented I too am a bit puzzled over exactly what you are asking.  But to answer your question, the Doctrine 2 Object Relation Manager can sort and group:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: What I want to do is not to do sorts and groupbys on the mysql, because the tables are myisam with around 100GB Data every month. If you do a sort or groupby the whole thing takes forever to copy to tmp-table etc.

I'd like to to the sort and the groupby in PHP.
Sure I can use array_sort etc and reinvent a wrapper which takes my arguments and mulitsorts and groups data. But I think that there may be some smart guys which have already done this.

Comment: It will always be slower to do this in PHP.  Make a copy of your data in a table type that works and use the database, thats what its for.

Comment: Several orders of magnitude slower.